# Мистика Python GUI (Kivy) и Multiprocessing | При создании процесса открывается ещё одно окно GUI

Tags: python, многопоточность, kivy, pyinstaller, multiprocessing

При запуске данного файла *.py* двойным щелчком, открывается терминал, GUI, и код работает без нареканий. *(Работаю через обычный IDLE 3.9)*

Однако, **если Python файл скомпилировать в .exe** при помощи того же pyinstaller, **когда я нажимаю кнопку**, в моём приложении, **то программа накладывает поверх основго окна приложения ещё одно**, и так можно создать хоть 200 одинаковых окон. При этом скрипт run_bot() не запускается. (Компилирую с терминалом, конечно же.)

*Для удобства есть видеозапись* - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tdpZCc33OI

**Вот мой простенький код**, который при нажатии на кнопку должен запускать функцию *run_bot()*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
def run_bot():
    while True:
        print('Working...')
        time.sleep(2)
    
class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
            self.btn=Button(
                        text='Старт',
                        font_size=30,
                        on_press=self.start,
                        background_color=(1,3,3,10)
                        )
            return self.btn
        def start(self,instance):
            self.proc=mp.Process(target=run_bot)
            self.proc.daemon=True
            self.proc.start() 
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: @Интик Демон же говорит о том, что необходимо завершить процесс после завершения работы программы.. Мне это необходимо...

Comment: Попробуйте перед `MyApp().run()` добавить `mp.freeze_support()`. Хотя это по идее может помочь только если RuntimeError выкидывает: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support

Comment: В общем, есть такое issue: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4744 В первом сообщении, как я понял, товарищ пишет, что приходится импорты самого kivy (ну и соответственно весь код от них зависящий) прятать под `if __name__ == '__main__':`, тогда дополнительные окна не спавнятся. По сути окно создается в момент импорта kivy, и если импорт не скрыть за `if __name__ == '__main__':`, то каждый процесс будет создавать свое окно.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо огромное! По поводу второго способа буду думать, если появятся новые косяки. 10/10!

Comment: В общем посмотрите куски кода в том issue, там есть какие-то другие варианты, может быть что-то подойдет.